# read a table with specified file format

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have to read a file using this file format:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT FF_CSV
    TYPE = CSV
    COMPRESSION = GZIP
    RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n'
    FIELD_DELIMITER = 'µµµ'
    FILE_EXTENSION = 'csv'
    SKIP_HEADER = 0
    SKIP_BLANK_LINES = TRUE
    DATE_FORMAT = AUTO
    TIME_FORMAT = AUTO
    TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = AUTO
    BINARY_FORMAT = UTF8
    ESCAPE = NONE --may need to set to '<character>'
    ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = NONE --may need to set to '<character>'
    TRIM_SPACE = TRUE
    FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"' --may need to set to '<character>'
    NULL_IF = '' --( '<string>' [ , '<string>' ... ] )
    ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = TRUE
    REPLACE_INVALID_CHARACTERS = TRUE
    VALIDATE_UTF8 = TRUE
    EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = TRUE
    SKIP_BYTE_ORDER_MARK = FALSE
    ENCODING = UTF8
;
```

For now I just want to test whether this definition would work correctly with my file or not. However, I am uncertain about how I can test for this. This is how I upload the file to my Snowflake stage:

```
put file://Users/myname/Desktop/leg.csv @:~
```

Now, how can I use `FILE FORMAT FF_CSV`in a select statement such that I can read my uploaded file using that format?

Answer (score -1):

You would use a copy into statement to pull the data from the stage into a table.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html

I would also recommend checking out some of these pages around Loading data into Snowflake.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide-data-load.html